# Converting python value of dictionary from list to float

Tags: python

I usually program in another language but need python for something currently.  I would like to convert the strings from this python dictionary to floats, but the tips I've read online aren't working exactly as I'd hoped.

```
example= dict({'Baker': '16,765',
 'Benton': '93,590',
 'Clackamas': '419,425',
 'Clatsop': '39,200',
 'Columbia': '51,900',
 'Coos': '63,275'})
```

The following results in only taking the first integer

```
for key in example.keys():
    example[key] = [float(example[key][0]),float(example[key][1])]
example

Out[]: 
{'Baker': [1.0, 6.0],
 'Benton': [9.0, 3.0],
 'Clackamas': [4.0, 1.0],
 'Clatsop': [3.0, 9.0],
 'Columbia': [5.0, 1.0],
 'Coos': [6.0, 3.0]}
```

And the following is still a string

```
{k:(map(float, example[k])) for k in example}
example

Out[]: 
{'Baker': '16,765',
 'Benton': '93,590',
 'Clackamas': '419,425',
 'Clatsop': '39,200',
 'Columbia': '51,900',
 'Coos': '63,275'}
```

I'm hoping you can help.  I'm using python3.  Thanks.

Comment: So, you want an array of floats, like `[16.0, 765.0]` for baker?

Comment: Can you show the expected result? I’m a bit confused by _only taking the first integer_: Your data seems to be the population for different U.S counties, so `16,765` is just a single number.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  This helped me realize that my main problem was the commas in the numbers.  I added the solution below. Slack will let me mark this as solved in 22 more hours. (1) remove the commas from the numbers with `example.replace(',','',regex=True)` (2) change the data type with `convert_dict = {'column_name': int}`  and then `dataframe = dataframe.astype(convert_dict)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.

This helped me realize that my main problem was the commas in the numbers.
I was able to remove the commas at the source with `example.replace(',','',regex=True)`

And then I was able to change the data type

```
convert_dict = {'column_name': int}
dataframe = dataframe.astype(convert_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've made a few mistakes. Using curly brackes, keys and values already defines a `dict`. You don't need to call `dict()` again. Then you either use `dict` comprehension, or the `map` function, but you don't need both. Lastly, you have to replace the comma with a dot to make the conversion work.

```
example = {
    'Baker': '16,765',
    'Benton': '93,590',
    'Clackamas': '419,425',
    'Clatsop': '39,200',
    'Columbia': '51,900',
    'Coos': '63,275'
}

in_float = {k: float(i.replace(',', '.')) for k, i in example.items()}
print(in_float)
```

Comment: This is *probably* not what the question's asking.

Comment: I thought it was. What is the question about?

Comment: Refer to quamrana's answer for what is likely what the question is asking.

Comment: Oohhhh... I guess you're right. I'll leave it for now though.

Comment: worked for my requirement though.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the `int` values instead of a string, you just need this:

```py
example = {'Baker': '16,765',
 'Benton': '93,590',
 'Clackamas': '419,425',
 'Clatsop': '39,200',
 'Columbia': '51,900',
 'Coos': '63,275'}

for key in example:
    s = example[key]
    example[key] = [int(item) for item in s.split(',')]

print(example)
```

Output:

```
{'Baker': [16, 765], 
'Benton': [93, 590], 
'Clackamas': [419, 425], 
'Clatsop': [39, 200], 
'Columbia': [51, 900], 
'Coos': [63, 275]}
```

Alternatively: `[float(item) for item in s.split(',')]` would make each value a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a nifty one-liner:

```py
example = {
    'Baker': '16,765',
    'Benton': '93,590',
    'Clackamas': '419,425',
    'Clatsop': '39,200',
    'Columbia': '51,900',
    'Coos': '63,275'
}

new_dict = {k: [float(i) for i in v.split(',')]
            for k, v in example.items()}

# pretty print the output
from pprint import pprint
pprint(new_dict)
```